# find difference of 2 images that may also be different sizes

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, diff, difference

I have 2 pdf files that have multiple layers of images.
The images are black and white diagrams and should be almost identical.

Problem is that the position of the diagrams in the canvas may be offset by a little (>3%) and they may be scaled to slightly different sizes, the size difference is small (>3%)

Is there a way to manipulate the images to minimise their difference by translation and scaling and then highlight the differences?

Comment: Try instead extracting the images from the PDFs using `pdfimages` tool from the Poppler suite.

Comment: Line diagrams are very hard to match if even slight changes. But you could extract the images from the PDF as Mark Setchell suggested, then dilate the two images with morphologic dilate, in ImageMagick, enough that the lines overlap better, then do the compare. You could post an example of a pair of your images and we could try some thing.